# Laravel8x: don't create FK with poll_id with Factory

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-8, tinker

I have two models Poll and DuplicatePoll

with the respective tables:

```
Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();           
        $table->text('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('duplicate_polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('poll_id');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->foreign('poll_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('polls');
    });
```

when i go to create a value for DuplicatePolls with tinker i get the following error:

> > > App\Models\DuplicatePoll::factory()->create(['poll_id'=>10]);
> > > PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Models/DuplicatePoll' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

in the DuplicatePoll factory:

```
    <?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\DuplicatePoll;
use App\Models\Poll;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class DuplicatePollFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = duplicatePoll::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
                'poll_id' => Poll::factory()->create(),
        ];
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

i ran a composer-dump autoload and now i get the error:

App\Models\DuplicatePoll::factory()->create(['poll_id'=>10]);
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `duplicate_polls` (`poll_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (10, 2020-11-19 11:49:32, 2020-11-19 11:49:32))'

Comment: you don't have an `updated_at` field, you will have to configure the model to not automatically use that timestamp field

Comment: to which model are you referring to the two? possible to have an example?